# Why is 看来 in the sentence 照他的年纪看来,他显得年轻？

Tags: usage

I'm trying to dissect this sentence on [jukuu.com](http://jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E5%B9%B4%E7%BA%AA):

> 照他的年纪看来,他显得年轻。 
>   He looks young considering his age.
>   <sub>(Zhào tāde niánjì kànlái, tā xiǎndé niánqīng.)</sub>

- [照](http://dict.cn/%E7%85%A7) (zhào) I think is short for [比照](http://dict.cn/%E6%AF%94%E7%85%A7) (bǐ zhào) = in contrast with
- [年纪](http://dict.cn/%E5%B9%B4%E7%BA%AA) (niánjì) = age
- [看来](http://dict.cn/%E7%9C%8B%E6%9D%A5) (kànlái) = seems
- [显得](http://dict.cn/%E6%98%BE%E5%BE%97) (xiǎndé) = seems [again (!?)]
- [年轻](http://dict.cn/%E5%B9%B4%E8%BD%BB) (niánqīng) = young.

I'm puzzled as to why "seems" appears twice here.  I think 他显得年轻 makes sense by itself ("he seems young"), so adding 看来 doesn't make sense to me.

**Question**: Why is 看来 in the sentence 照他的年纪看来,他显得年轻？

I'm thinking it might be used to indicate some suspicion of his age, e.g., if a child was buying alcohol with a fake ID.  Or maybe I'm reading too much into this.

Comment: 看来 bkrs：根据事况加以观察推论。
hence （see given translation） 照。。。看来 can mean "considering 。。。" cf。
 以我看来 in my opinion,这样看来  from this point of view

Comment: 年纪 is not used correctly here, it should be 年龄。 年纪 is estimated age according to apperance / behavior / style, etc, while 年龄 used to refer actual age of a man. e.g. 年纪轻轻就开始做生意 means it looks like a young boy/girl, we are not care of actual age of him/her.    "他显得年轻" talks about "年纪", 照他的年纪，来讨论年纪，本身是不合逻辑的, the statement is not logical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this sentence seems good to me, I think it can be better phrased as:

照他的年纪**来看**,他显得年轻。

And 照 ... 来看 can be considered as a set phrase meaning “considering”

Answer (score 1):

first,照...看来this is a chinese idiom(习惯用语)。e.g:照我看来，这件事可以这样做，user6065 's moment is what it mean,依据某人的看法/想法来判断。
second,they are different things,there arent two "seems",the meaning between them is different in Chinese。"显得"是一种动作性(verb)，e.g:u looks very young.带着与某些参照而表现出来的样子。

Answer (score 1):

To me, as an interpreter for 'considering' or 'in contrast with' in the context, the phrase 和...相比 is more clear than 照...来看/看来.

So, I would translate this to 和他的年龄相比， 他显得很年轻.

Answer (score 1):

This 照 is 按照 in my opinion, and yeah, I agree with fefe, sounds much better with 来看。

（按）照他的年纪来看,他显得年轻。 
He looks younger than he is.

I don't think there is a Chinese linguist checking what jukuu puts on its webpage. Take it with a pinch of salt.

Comment: 看来 or 来看 doesn't make much difference. For example, 照我看来 and 照我来看，  you wouldn't win any additional point by using 照我来看 against 照我看来.